# Creating SQLite3 Database on Mac

Tags: sqlite

I apologize for the extremely noobish quesetion, though I could not understand the answer provided here: [Where is SQLite database stored on disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074273/where-is-sqlite-database-stored-on-disk). When creating a table within the SQLite3 shell via these commands as suggested here ([Bulk load data into sqlite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697004/bulk-load-data-into-sqlite)):

```
 sqlite3 myDatabase
 create table myTable (a, b, c);
 .separator ','
 .import  myFile  myTable
```

I was not able to determine where "myDatabase" is actually saved to. Could someone please help me understand which folder it is typically saved to on a Mac, or how I could specify a folder to save it to.

Thanks so much for your help and patience

Comment: It is saved to the "current working directory" (unless other path information is supplied in the filename). This should be the directory you were in the shell which launched sqlite3. See "cd", "cwd" and "ls" commands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will create the SQLite database where your terminal window currently is, which is usually your user profile folder:

[image]

You can go to that folder by going to :

[image]