# In python, when using sqlite3 where are databases stored physically?

Tags: python, sqlite

Sorry for the basic questions. I'm starting to work with Python. I'm using Windows 10, Python 3.5, Notepad++ as editor. Python is installed in `z:\python35` and scripts are in `z:\python\sqlite`, then my script is really simple:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('sample.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE example (name VARCHAR)")
conn.close()
```

When I run the script inside Notepad++ (run as administrator) I execute `z:\python35\python.exe -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`. Looks like the script runs correctly, since it does nothing the first time run, but the next time it says:

**`sqlite3.OperationalError: table example already exits`**

And that's okay because I wanted to create the database and the table. Thing is, where does this **`sample.db`** is stored? I don't find it in the python directory or my projects directory. Not even by searching in Windows.

How can I delete the whole database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is SQLite database stored on disk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074273/where-is-sqlite-database-stored-on-disk)

Comment: Nop... I read that one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

probably in the "current directory" that notepadd++ uses. try to add on top of script:

```
import os
print(u"current directory: %s" % os.getcwdu())
```

maybe you could specify an absolute path for the db do deal with that uncertainty

Comment: by the way, to get the directory path of the current python file: os.path.dirname(\_\_file\_\_)

Answer (score 3):

It will be in the current working directory. You can see what this is by

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

Once you know the directory you can find and delete the `sample.db` file.

Comment: Great. It says it is in the Notepad++ directory. Never thought of it. I thought that using `$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)` would make it my working directory, looks like it only tells python the full name of the script file.

Thanks a lot. Now I have a different problem :-)

Comment: You can change your working directory using the os module, so you can have the file somewhere sensible.

Comment: I'll do what Stephan recommends: to use an absolute path

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need the databases to persist on your file system, you can store them in memory using the special `:memory:` name:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
```

Comment: OK, great to know. I'll use this thing later, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to change your current working directory like this:

```
#import os module

import os, sqlite3

#change cwd to the given absolute path with a raw string.
absolute_path = r"z:\db\directory_for_db"
os.chdir(absolute_path)
# connect to database
conn = sqlite3.connect('sample.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE example (name VARCHAR)")
conn.close()
```

Which will result in your .db being saved wherever you define absolute_path